# System.OverflowException on converting string 0x255 to byte

Tags: c#, byte

I'm not sure why did I get it... Got any ideas why?

**Code:**

```
data[i] = Convert.ToByte(build, 16);
```

where the `build` is a `string` with value **0x255** other convert is working fine for me **0x04** for example. It just got stuck at that value

Comment: It should be `0xFF`, not `0x255` (which is beoynd byte range: `0x255 == 597`)

Comment: Take another look at the Docs about [Convert.ToByte(String, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks man!. Solved it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing *decimal* and *hexadecimal*:

```
0xFF  (hex) == 255 
0x255 (hex) == 597 which is beyond byte range [0..255]
```

Please, note that

```
0x04  (hex) == 4   and that's why you have a correct result
```

In your case the code should be either

```
// build == "255" and build is decimal
data[i] = Convert.ToByte(build, 10);
```

or

```
// build is hexadecimal, but "0x255" is an incorrect value
build = "0xFF";
...
data[i] = Convert.ToByte(build, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal values go from `0x00` to `0xFF` (0-255).

So `0x255` does not exist as a byte. The value you are looking for instead of `0x255` is `0xFF`.